# Cannot select "Cordova" item when adding app in App center for code push

Tags: cordova, code-push

Good day.

I use appcenter for my cordova app for codepush. Today I wanted to add another android cordova app in appcenter, but when I choose Android or IOS os, there is no "Cordova" item in Platform list. But earlier it was here and I added cordova apps.

Does anyone knows what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find the answer here: https://newswwc.com/technology/dotnet-technologies/announcing-apache-cordova-retirement/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.